# Mysql Select data and time

Tags: php, mysql, select

Well i writing betting script got all data in mysql 
Table Games row BetillDate row BetillTime

```
BetillDate| BetillTime
--------------------
2015-01-21|15:00:00| 
2015-01-29|15:00:00| 
2015-01-27|15:00:00|
```

How to Mysql Select Date its today and time its now in one select...
This select not working right ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT
class.`name`
FROM
class
INNER JOIN market ON class.game_id = market.class_id
WHERE
market.betTillDate > NOW() AND
market.betTillTime > NOW()
```

or if its not possible how can i do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Store them in the same field obviously.  The `DATETIME` datatype in MySQL can store them in one field, so why are you separating them into two fields?

Comment: Please show us the data types of  `BetillDate` and `BetillTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
class.`name`
FROM
class
INNER JOIN market ON class.game_id = market.class_id
WHERE
TIMESTAMP(market.betTillDate,market.betTillTime) > NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest fixing the database by adding a field of `DATETIME` type and concatenating those two fields into it.

```
Alter table TABLEX add BetillDateTime DATETIME;
Update TABLEX set BetillDateTime = TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(BetillDate,' ',BetillTime));
```

Now you have a single field for both date and time, and should fix your code to use only that one, then later drop the other two.

And now all you need in the where clause is:

```
WHERE market.BetillDateTime > NOW()
```